# how to send FCM message to MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show FCM received message in my mainActivity as a bottomNavigation badge,
but how can I send data to activity from services?
I used:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.putExtra("badge", p0.notification?.body)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

but this code open new MainActivity, while there's another one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sending a `LocalBroadcast` if your service and activity run in the same process.

```
// Inside the service
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)
    val lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
    val dataIntent = Intent().apply { 
        putExtra("badge", p0.notification?.body) 
    }
    lbm.sendBroadcast(dataIntent)
}
```

```
// Inside the activity
private val lbm by lazy { LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this) }
private val badgeListener = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(ctx: Context, data: Intent) {        
         val count = intent.getIntExtra("badge")
         // Update the view here
    }
}


override fun onCreate(){
    // Other stuff
    lbm.registerReceiver(badgeListener)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    lbm.unregisterReceiver(badgeListener)
}
```